# How to upload files sequentially in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, azure, angular5

I currently have a solution that uploads multiple files to Azure Blob Storage, but the progress bar does not reset after each file (stays at 100).

I know you can use a Promise but I'm new to Angular and don't know how to approach it best?

This is my current code (that works) it stores the files in an array

uploadFiles()
  {

```
while (this.targetFiles.length > 0)
{
    this.targetFile = this.targetFiles.pop();
    this.uploadProgress = this.blob
    .uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, this.targetFile);


    this.currentPageSub = 
    this.uploadProgress.subscribe((total: number) => {
      this.progress=total;
          });

}
```

}

But i want to upload the files one at a time, resetting the progress bar (this.progress) in the subscribe function after a file has been uploaded

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried resetting this.progress to 0 in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the progress in every cycle.

```
 while (this.targetFiles.length > 0)
{
    this.progress=0;
    this.targetFile = this.targetFiles.pop();
    this.uploadProgress = this.blob
    .uploadToBlobStorage(accessToken, this.targetFile);


    this.currentPageSub = 
    this.uploadProgress.subscribe((total: number) => {
      this.progress=total;
          });

 } 
}
```

Comment: I had this, but it does not reset which is why I started looking into Promises, If i choose 1 small file and 1 big file, The small file goes straight to 100, then the big file goes to 0 then no progress is shown on the subscribe like it's been reset

Comment: From looking at the console.log it seems that its just sending both files to be uploaded instead of waiting for one then doing the other, Im going to try set up another suvscription but for the second file to see if i can track progress of the two at the same time

Comment: It's better if you can create a stackblitz so I can have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Won't be able to show the uploading on stackblitz as I have to provide an access token for the blob storage and I don't really want that being public...